# how to group the components to a fixed position on the screen in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, css

i am designing an registration page in asp.net.to group the components(label, ddl and text boxes) i am using panels,but while  running the page positions of components are changing. How to fix components to a particular position?

thanks with regards,
radha

Comment: You need to provide an example for the issue (the HTML and CSS).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Table Tag 
For Example

Answer (score 0):

better to add all the controls in a page to a table and set the table row and column position
E.g:

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
                        <table>
                        <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label> 
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                    </asp:Panel>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
```

Comment: That's not necessarily 'better'. You can create awesome, fluent CSS forms that are table less.  You can't provide a solution to a problem before you see/know the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the cssclass property of your panel element.  An absurd example follows. (It still proves the concept)


`<style type="text/css">
    .pi
    {
        position:fixed;

        top:100px;

        left:100px;

        height:100px;

        background-color:Red;

        width:1000px;

    }
</style>

        <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" CssClass="pi" runat="server">

                                        <asp:TextBox ID="t1" runat="server" />

        </asp:Panel>`

Answer (score 0):

Don't [give up and use tables](http://giveupandusetables.com/), for statically positioned elements I'll simply apply absolute positioning CSS, either to divs surrounding the elements or to the elements themselves:

```
.staticPosition
{
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:20px;
}
```